# erro Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

Estou com um erro na minha ação no meu console apesenta o seguinte erro Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

alguém poderia me ajuda vou deixar link do scripet e da pagina onde sta rodando o script aqui nao sei oque estou fazendo de errado 
https://jefferson-bruno-veneros-stella-799bed.webflow.io/

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#herobotslider div:nth-child(2)').trigger('tap');
});

var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {
  var l = $('#herobotslider .w-slider-arrow-left');
  var r = $('#herobotslider .w-slider-arrow-right');
  $('#heroslidernav')
    .on('click', '.slider-left', function() {
      l.trigger('tap');
    })
    .on('click', '.slider-right', function() {
      r.trigger('tap');
    });
});

  var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {
  var l = $('.hero-img-slider .w-slider-arrow-left');
  var r = $('.hero-img-slider .w-slider-arrow-right');
  $('#heroslidernav')
    .on('click', '.slider-left', function() {
      l.trigger('tap');
    })
    .on('click', '.slider-right', function() {
      r.trigger('tap');
    });
});


  var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {
  var l = $('#herobotslider .w-slider-arrow-left');
  var r = $('#herobotslider .w-slider-arrow-right');
  $('#hrs')
    .on('click', '.sss', function() {
      l.trigger('tap');
    })
    .on('click', '.hero-bottom-slider-div', function() {
      r.trigger('tap');
    });
});

  var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {
  var l = $('.hero-img-slider .w-slider-arrow-left');
  var r = $('.hero-img-slider .w-slider-arrow-right');
  $('#hrs')
    .on('click', '.sss', function() {
      l.trigger('tap');
    })
    .on('click', '.hero-bottom-slider-div', function() {
      r.trigger('tap');
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está entrando em um loop infinito.

quando chama o "tap" no `#herobotslider` você chama o tap nele mesmo.

Mesmo você indicando a classe `#herobotslider .qualquer` vai ser chamado primeiro o clique no #herobotslider.